How to dimension a solar battery charger?
I am currently designing my first PCB and I am having some difficulties. It will be a solar power management board with a USB input, li-ion battery, PV module and a not yet defined 7.2 V output connection. I have already put a few things together, but now I have a few questions:

If the battery is fully charged and the USB (5 V, 3 A) or a theoretical PV module of 6 V and 18 W (~3 A) is connected, will the amount of current under maximum possible full load at V_OUT be 0.54 A or 3 A?

What is the smallest possible 4.2 V PV-module that can be used? (I am looking for the wattage.)




windijon - Hi, FYI I have rolled-back (reversed) the edit that deleted the schematic, since the schematic is required for this question to make sense. TY

@windijon  I did see your proposal to have the input to the output stage boost converter be either from USB or Battery, so that USB could provide more than 0.54A of the load.   That approach is OK if the attached USB power source can provide ALL the power for the load. Many USB chargers will only supply 1.5A or 2.4A at 5V, only type-C will reach 3A.  That circuit (similar to the one selecting between solar and USB into charger) is a "switch" that favors the USB, rather than a method to share load between multiple sources. The other option is larger charger circuit that can supply the load too.

Regarding first question about what limits the output current of the design....
The supply for the 7.2V V_OUT is the U8 (MT3608) DC-DC converter boost circuit, and the supply for the boost circuit is the BATTERY.  So assuming the battery is well sized (impossible to guess without a battery data sheet), output current would be limited only by the maximum current allowed by the U8 DC-DC boost circuit design, which is probably about 1A based on quick review of MT3608 datasheet, (but impossible to confirm without ratings for L2 and D3, and thermal design details).
The other two supply inputs, USB plug and PV solar panel input, can only reach the battery through the U9 (CN3163) charging circuit, which the schematic note says is set to be limited to 0.54A, an that current maximum only applies during constant-current mode.  So the full power of those supplies is not really available to power V_OUT via the battery node.
Regarding the second question about minimum size for PV solar panel.....  There is no minimum power requirement for PV solar panel if you believe the U9 (CN3163) datasheet, which claims the charging controller will lower battery charging current automatically if input current from solar panel is limited (see section "Charging Current limited by the Output capability of Input Power Supply" on page 7 of CN3136 datasheet, as long as the solar panel voltage remains above 4.4V.  So the minimum power (size) for the PV solar panel would be determined by only by maximum time the user is willing to wait for the battery to charge.

thank you very much
